# No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

```
h5py
Keras==2.0.3
numpy
opencv-python
sklearn
tensorflow 2.0 >
```

I'm getting the following error message

> Using TensorFlow backend. 2020-04-02 01:53:58.259516: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1 Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "train_frcnn.py", line 10, in 
>       from keras import backend as K   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/**init**.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from . import applications   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/applications/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from .vgg16 import VGG16   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       from ..models import Model   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/models.py", line 14, in
>   
>       from . import layers as layer_module   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/layers/**init**.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from ..engine import Layer   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/engine/**init**.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from .training import Model   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from .. import callbacks as cbks   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
> packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 25,
>   in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector ModuleNotFoundError: No 
> module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Answer (score 2):

`keras-2.0.3` does not support `tensorflow-2.x`:

https://keras.io/#multi-backend-keras-and-tfkeras

> The current release is Keras 2.3.0, which makes significant API changes and add support for TensorFlow 2.0.

You must update your `keras` to `2.3.0` or higher (try `python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade keras`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the aforementioned answer, there are other two aspects to be taken into consideration:

1. 'tensorflow.contrib' has been removed from the packages.
2. Use **Keras inside TensorFlow** as even Francois Chollet mentioned, since Keras version 2.3 is the last major release of Keras, there will be minor support after this release. Moreover, the Keras inside TensorFlow is more up-to-date and less prone to errors.